# How to use C++ enums without getting a compiler warning

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enums

I need to communicate that one and the same enum is passed to several calls. So I am doing this:

```
MiddleEarth::Creatures ally = MiddleEarth::Creatures::Elf;

myEnergy->Transfer(ally, 10);
myLives->Transfer(ally, 1);
```

Both Transfer methods are declared as follows:

```
Energy::Transfer(const Creatures& transferTo, (snip)
```

However, I am getting the following warning on the declaration of the variable named ally:

```
 warning C4482: nonstandard extension used: enum 'MiddleEarth::Creatures' used in qualified name
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I rewrite my code so that it does not generate a compiler warning?

Comment: yes, oops this is C++

Comment: "How to do XYZ without getting a compiler warning" - this kind of title always develops an urge deep inside me to answer "by writing your code correctly"...

Comment: What version of MSVC?

Comment: You can use `enum class`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [MSDN page on the warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173704(v=vs.110).aspx);

> When you refer to an enum inside a type, you do not need to specify the name of the enum.
>
> int i = S::E::a;   // C4482
>   int j = S::a;   // OK

so in your case;

```
MiddleEarth::Creatures::Elf
```

should be

```
MiddleEarth::Elf
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want:

```
MiddleEarth::Creatures ally = MiddleEarth::Elf;
```